# .htaccess to combine files

Tags: .htaccess

I found the following htacess that allows concatenation from within specific js files

```
<FilesMatch "\.combined\.js$">
  Options +Includes
  AddOutputFilterByType INCLUDES application/javascript application/json
  SetOutputFilter INCLUDES
</FilesMatch>
```

e.g. Inside of script.combined.js you could have

```
 < !--#include file="libs/jquery-1.5.0.min.js" -->
 < !--#include file="plugins/jquery.idletimer.js" -->
```

and they would be included into this single file.

I want to know how do these two line  -  line 2 n 3 of the .htaccess combine files.

Also these have worked on several systems but on my ubuntu 12.04 with Apache 2.2.22 they don't work. why?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to use .htaccess for this. You'll end up with a more maintainable and reliable result in **any** scripting language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first line enables Includes also known as SSI ([server-side includes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes)) for the two mime types: `application/javascript` and `application/json`

The second line `SetOutputFilter INCLUDES` processes the files for includes before outputing them but only for the files contained in the regex path `"\.combined\.js$"` and basically does what the first is doing but it's a backup.

Your missing a crucial `Option` flag. And that's `Options +Includes` to enable includes to begin with. That may be why it is not working on the other server

I hope your not including that space after the `<` and it was a typo because surely that will not work on any version of apache if I'm not mistaken. It should be without spaces as follows:

```
<!--#include file="libs/jquery-1.5.0.min.js" -->
<!--#include file="plugins/jquery.idletimer.js" -->
```

You will also need to enable `mod_include` module in your Apache httpd.conf. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_include.html

`LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so`

I'm pretty sure you got this code from the HTML5-Boilerplate .htaccess

https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/.htaccess#L887-L917

Comment: Yes i got it from Boilerplate

Comment: yes the space was just for SO to not ignore it. Let me try mod_include right away and update you

Comment: @WebDeveloper Great! Feel free to mark the question as answered then.

Comment: waiting for any better answer coz it's worth 50 pts.... Tom the bonus ends i will vote u then

Comment: @WebDeveloper Strange because I don't see a bounty offered. You can change accepted answers. How much better are you going to get anyways.

Comment: yes.. strange what happened to it.... BTW how did u find this question... It's a very old question

Answer (score 0):

The actual explanation is here:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#addoutputfilterbytype

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#setoutputfilter

Instructions on how to use those two functions are in the above links.  Basically apache applies filters before sending the results to the client to be processed by the browser.  Thus the result looks to be append the files into one file.

Apache actually deprecated that AddOutputFilterByType and no longer supports its' use after apache 2.1 :( I think that is the reason for those functions not to work on 2.2.22.